# Retorna incorrecto resultado la función

Tags: python, python-3.x

1) Escribe un programa para ayudar a una empresa que desea asignar sueldos para los cargos de sus trabajadores. La lista es la siguiente:

> Ejecutivo: 90
>
> Jefe: 100
>
> Externo: 50

La variable cargo contiene el nombre del cargo (por ejemplo, "Externo"). Recuerda entregar tu resultado modificando únicamente la variable dinero.

2) Escribe un código que calcule el cuadrado de un número si este es impar, o el cubo de un número si este es par. Por ejemplo, para 4 tu programa debe entregar 64, y para 3 debe entregar 9.

```
    def exponenciacion(numero):
  resultado = numero

  if numero %2 == 0:
    numero = numero ** 3

  else:
    numero = numero ** 2

  return resultado
```

Realice ese codigo y me dice que tengo un error. Lo corrí en my Pycharms y excelente! Pero en el curso me dice que esta mal

Comment: Qué intentaste para el primer punto?

Comment: Es imposible que funcione en cualquier lado. El problema es que al final, la función `exponenciacion` devuelve el valor de la variable `resultado`, pero la función no está realmente guardando el resultado en esa variable, sino en la variable `numero`.

Comment: Diego,en realidad la variable que retornas que es "resultado", no esta realizando ninguna operación, retorna la variable "numero". Para realizar preguntas dale un vistazo a [ask], saludos.

Comment: creo que tienes problemas de identacion

Answer (score 2):

Dentro del `if` y el `else` no es la variable `número` a la que le debes asignar el resultado es a `resultado`.

```
def exponenciacion(numero):
 resultado = numero

 if numero %2 == 0:
  resultado = numero ** 3

 else:
  resultado = numero ** 2

return resultado
```

Míralo [link](https://repl.it/@meerkat999/KnownFruitfulBarnswallow)

Answer (score 0):

Realiza la operación con la misma variable `numero`, ya que retorna el mismo valor porque aunque asignas  `resultado = numero` , no realizas operaciones con la variable `resultado`,

esto debe solucionar el problema:

```
def exponenciacion(numero):    
    if numero %2 == 0:        
        numero = numero ** 3
    else:        
        numero = numero ** 2
    return numero
```

o bien, debes usar la variable `resultado` para asignar el valor de las operaciones:

```
def exponenciacion(numero):   
    resultado = numero 
    if numero %2 == 0:        
        resultado = numero ** 3
    else:        
        resultado  = numero ** 2
    return resultado
```

[**Ejemplos**](https://www.ideone.com/mGb9m1):

```
print exponenciacion(90)
print exponenciacion(100)
print exponenciacion(50)
```

Salida:

```
729000
1000000
125000
```

Comment: y cual es el error para asignar -1?

Answer (score -2):

Para la 1) lo hice así:

```
def sueldo(cargo):
dinero = 0
if dinero == 50:
print("Externo")
elif dinero == 90:
print("Ejecutivo")
elif dinero == 100:
print("Jefe")
return dinero
Pero igual me sale error.. No sé cómo hacerlo

Ahora, la 3 lo hice así:

def es_primo(numero):
primo = True
if primo == True:
if numero == 3 or numero ==5 or numero==13:
  print("True")
elif numero == 1 or numero == 10 or numero ==33:
  print("False")
return primo


Ayuda a los novatos por favor. gracias!!
```

Comment: Por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Que tiene que ver esto con la pregunta formulada?